# In a movie booking system(eg BMS), how are seats temporarily blocked?

Tags: architecture, microservices

In microservices architecture, suppose we have a api that is doing the bookings. A user tries to book a seat and it fails at payment mode. The seat status is blocked for some time(2 mins). How can this seat be automatically released after 2 mins?

if we think of a batch job running at a frequency, it might release it after more than 2 mins depending on when it ran last.

What can be other solution to this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to accomplish this.  Two of the most common:

1. The service responsible for tracking seat availability for a given showing tracks reservations.  When a user begins the booking process for a seat, it records a reservation with a unique ID and an "expires at" timestamp for 1 seat.  If the booking is successful before the "expires at", the reservation is converted into an actual booking.  If the "expires at" timestamp passes by and the reservation has not been converted, the service reports those seats as available.  Whether and when the service then chooses to delete the reservation after that is an implementation detail (for instance, you might keep the stale reservations around and only cancel the oldest stale reservation when required for ensuring that the sum-total of active and stale reservations does not exceed the number of seats available).
2. You can define a scheduling service: submit a representation of, e.g., a request to a particular service along with a time.  The result of that submission is a token so that the schedule can be rescinded.  The service tracks the time of the next request/action and waits until that point to perform that request/action.

Note that any approach wherein a seat automatically becomes available if no purchase completes, there exists a situation where a seat is reserved and successfully paid for, but the seat is released back to the pool and bought by someone else, so some process(es) will have to be defined for handling those situations (e.g. reconciling payments with tickets issued).

Comment: Thanks for the revert. Could you please elaborate on point 2? if there are millions of users who have watsapp status' which expire after 24 hrs and for each individual that can be a separate time , so how we can design this ? As per point 2 above, a token with expiration time will be created but how will it be scheduled for millions of users at different timestamps?

Comment: For scheduling a lot of events, you may want to investigate hierarchical timing wheels.